# Update and self join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to update the blank name column in client table using the non-blank column with same client number. Do you know how I should modify the below SQL?  Thanks,

```
UPDATE CLIENT
    SET NAME=(SELECT NAME FROM CLIENT WHERE (NAME IS NOT NULL AND NAME<>'') )
FROM CLIENT C1, CLIENT C2
WHERE (NAME IS NULL OR NAME='') AND C1.CLIENT_NO=C2.CLIENT_NO
```

Comment: Cindy, we need to know what your table structure is, as well as what some data looks like before and after.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using window functions for this purpose:

```
with toupdate as (
      select c.*, max(name) over (partition by client_no) as maxname
      from client c
     )
update toupdate
    set name = maxname
    where name is null or name = '';
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Gordon Linoff!